# How to split array per each one index jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with arrays, and i have array:

```
var array = ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"];
```

I add this values dynamicaly to the div:

```
$(array).each(function (index, data) {
  var item = `<p>${data}</p>`
  $("#divId").append(item )
});
```

But i want to add in to div each second value, for example:

```
val2, val4 should be on the div.
```

How i can split array values?

Comment: Just check if `index` is even, ie `index % 2 === 0`. If index is even then skip, otherwise insert value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple trick, if index is even add it like:

```js
let array = ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"];

$(array).each(function(index, data) {
  let item = `<p>${data}</p>`
  if (index % 2 == 1) {    
    $("#one").append(item);
  } else {
    $("#two").append(item);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='one'></div>
<div id='two'></div>
```

Comment: This good, but val1, val3 i need to show in another div, how i can do his?

Comment: I change my example and add another `div`, simple if is `even` add into first `div` else in the second.

Comment: Thanks u are save me :)

Comment: *val1, val3 i need to show in another div, how i can do this* - by making sure you understand what's been provided and not just copy+paste.   The key part of the code is `index % 2 == 1` for "even" values (0 based, so it's actually the odd indices).   If you understand what this does, you will (easily) be able to determine how to get the other values (hint: not just `else`).  If you don't understand it then, sure, use it for now to get you going, but do come back to it and research how/why it works.

Comment: @freedomn-m the voice of truth :), you are right. Can you explaine me why not just an `else` ? you mean he can use `!` like that `if (index % 2 !== 1)` ?

Comment: I was thinking it's the `%` that OP needs to understand.  It's extremely useful long term.